# Signing a unique number to a row in postgresql based on another row

Tags: database, postgresql, concurrency

I am trying to uniquely identify users within an anonymous comment section. I have decided to have 256 unique identifiers. So I want to return a value of 0-255 for the post they made. I have this table for example:

```
create table post (
  reply_to int,         //post number they are replying to
  opUUID varchar(36),
  imageuuid varchar(36),
  contents varchar(1516),
  timestamp timestamp
)

create table identity (
   reply_to int,
   opUUID varchar(36),
   <unique value from 0-255> int,
)
```

Where this is a many post to one identity relation for the context of the comment section.

I was looking into using postgresql identities and passing in a function to it but I am unable to find a way to do this. When its the first opUUID (user) to comment on a post (reply_to) I would like to look at all other unique values assigned to other opUUIDs and assign a unique value not used yet to this new opUUID.

Comment: So the `post` table stores your comments? Or are comments and posts different entities?

Comment: What's the primary key of this `posts` table? And what is this `identity` table - is that where you are storing your users?

Comment: Dont understand why you have 255 unique values. Does that mean the 256th is now the same as the 1st?